# cannot delete last item from todo list

Tags: javascript

I've made a simple todo list which so far has 2 functions. Checks off an item and deletes an item from a list.

I can delete all items if I start deleted from the bottom of the list but when I delete from the top, the first item gets deleted, the second item (now the first), deletes the item after it and then doesn't delete itself when I click on the X

I thought a `stopPropagration()` would help but doesn't seem to. It only stops the other checked function from running.

```
<ul>
  <li><span>X</span> Code something</li>
  <li><span>X</span> Wake up early</li>
  <li><span>X</span> Buy popcorn</li>
</ul>
```

```
/**
 * This strikes through list item on click once and item is marked as done
 */
const listItem = document.getElementsByTagName('li')

for (let i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
  listItem[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    listItem[i].classList.toggle('checked')
  })
}

/**
 * This deletes an item from the list on click
 */
const deleteItem = document.getElementsByTagName('span')

for (let i = 0; i < deleteItem.length; i++) {
  deleteItem[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
    deleteItem[i].parentNode.remove()
    e.stopPropagation()
  })
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k2u8mqes/

Expected result is that I should be able to delete each item, in any order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is assigning some clicks to different elements from what you intend.

This suggestion uses the target of the `click` event to decide what needs to be deleted in real time. (Specifically, it removes the `li` that is the parent of the clicked `span`.)

```js
document.addEventListener("click", checkLi);
document.addEventListener("click", deleteSpanParent);

function checkLi(event){
  if(event.target.tagName == "LI"){
    event.target.classList.toggle("checked");
    event.target.style.color = "grey";
  }
}

function deleteSpanParent(event){
  if(event.target.tagName == "SPAN"){
    let span = event.target, li = span.parentNode, ul = li.parentNode;
    ul.removeChild(li);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>X</span> Code something</li>
  <li><span>X</span> Wake up early</li>
  <li><span>X</span> Buy popcorn</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are **modifying an array while iterating it**, which is a common caveat.
When you delete from top:

> 1. deletes the 1st item, calls `deleteItem[0].parentNode.remove()`, removes the 1st element of `deleteItem` array, it's okay;
> 2. deletes the 2nd item, calls `deleteItem[1].parentNode.remove()`, but the `deleteItem` is now of size 2, you are actually deleting the
>      3rd element of the original array;
> 3. deletes the 3rd item, calls `deleteItem[2].parentNode.remove()`, but the `deleteItem` is now of size 1, you are running out of index;

Working snippet:

```
for (let i = 0; i < deleteItem.length; i++) {
  deleteItem[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.target.parentNode.remove()
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where the way you have used for loops to bind event listeners and how you're using accessing the particular element which the event bound to.

Instead of doing this;

```
listItem[i].classList.toggle('checked')
//and
deleteItem[i].parentNode.remove()
```

You can use the event listener's event object to access to bound element, like this;

```
e.target.classList.toggle('checked')
//and
e.target.parentNode.remove()
```

Please refer to the event listener API here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

check this fiddle for a working example of your code : https://jsfiddle.net/491rLbxj/

Comment: this [link] https://gomakethings.com/why-you-shouldnt-attach-event-listeners-in-a-for-loop-with-vanilla-javascript/ explains where you've mistaken.